# Каким методом передается http-запрос в форме и без формы?

Tags: http, post, запрос, get, методы

Хочу понять, как работает метод GET и POST в http-запросе.

1) Правильно ли я понимаю, что по умолчанию при запросе любого сайта даже без формы (например, ввести в строку поиска mail.ru) браузер отправляет http-запрос веб-серверу методом GET? Вопрос возник, т.к. читая интернет, везде пишут, что эти запросы касаются отправки html-формы (тег `<form>`). Но не сказано, что это касается любого запроса.

2) Можно ли любой сайт без формы (без тега `<form>`) запросить у веб-сервера методом "POST" (например, тот же mail.ru)? И как это сделать? Ведь метод можно задавать только в теге `<form>`?

3) Можно ли при передаче http-запроса методом "POST" в теге `<form>` данные передать не только в теле запроса, но и в URL-е (как происходит при методе "GET")?

4) Можно ли при передаче http-запроса методом "POST" в теге `<form>` данные передать только в URL-е (как происходит при методе "GET"), но не передавать через тело запроса?

5) Существует ли интерфейс, чтобы вручную отправить http-запрос браузеру? Например, я не хочу вбивать mail.ru в строку поиска браузера. А хочу напряму отправить что-то вроде

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.ru
```

Куда мне это вбивать?

6) Можно ли часть сайта запросить у веб-сервера методом "GET", а остальное методом "POST"? Например, чтобы основная часть html-страницы запрашивалась методом "GET", а форма (тег "form") в ней методом "POST"?

Comment: Может я не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос. Просто меня меня интересует принципиальная разница. Например, я создаю сайт. Я разве не сам задаю, каким методом будет обрабатываться мой запрос, GET или POST?
В этом плане касаемо вопроса 2) Если я сам задаю метод, то я могу указать для сайта без формы метод "POST"? Или все же смысл метода "POST", как пишут в интернете, что данные методом "POST" передаются только при отправке формы в теле запроса, но не в URL-e и принимающий сервер просто не обработает такой запрос т.к. нет формы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню остальные ответы.
Важно понимать что запрос - это обычная строка. Вы привели в 5-ом вопросе пример запроса в 2 строки, но на самомо деле это строка с символом переноса посередине.

В свою очередь `http` - это не какая-то магия. Это просто протокол. Набор правил если хотите, по которой эта самая строка должна формироваться. Отправитель(браузер, или другой инструмент) и получатель(сервер) просто договорились между собой, каким именно образом один будет формировать эту строку, а второй парсить, чтоб оба могли друг друга понять. Например стандартизированы статусы, некоторые заголовки.

`GET` и `POST` - это тоже не магия. Это просто ключевые слова, которые подсказывают серверу, где искать данные.(Есть еще PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD и многие другие. Добавлены просто для соблюдения семантики).

Из понимания что же это такое, "протокол `http`", вытекает понимание всех остальных Ваших вопросов.Например ответ на вопрос №2. Чтоб послать запрос, Вам не обязательно нужен браузер. Вам нужен инструмент, способный "сформировать" строку по "правилам", заложенным в протоколе и отправить ее. Такой инструмент присутствует во всех известных мне языках программирования в том или ином виде.

Comment: Возникает вопрос, могу ли я браузером, который умеет принимать http-запросы отправить такой запрос: POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.ru  , где mysite.ru - мой созданный сайт на html, но без формы. Или меня принимающий сервер не поймет? Если так, то правильно ли я понимаю, что метод POST можно задать только для формы и данные будут передаваться только в теле запроса (смысл метода)? При методе GET в форме данные будут передаваться в URL-e? Во всех остальных случаях (без формы и прочее) данные передаются методом GET?

Comment: Смотрите, это не POST,GET запросы используют формы для своей работы, а формы используют POST,GET запросы. Сами запросы существуют отдельно, могут работать и без форм, но вот формы без запросов смысла иметь не будут. Если мы говорим о браузере, то Вам уже ответили что послать пост запрос можно 2 путями: формой и сформировать его через `JavaScript`(В этом случае можно без формы), например [так](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Если Вам хочется прям ручками сформировать запрос, то методики сделать это через браузер мне не известны.

Comment: Я не понял что Вы спросили про (смысл метода)? Вам не понятно зачем разделили GET и POST?

Comment: Т.е. правильно ли я понимаю, что назначение GET - получить данные с сервера, а также передача параметров в URL. А POST - только передача параметров в теле запроса, но не в URL? Т.е. следуя логике, сайт с формой, у которой указан метод "POST", запрашивается все-таки методом GET (получить html-данные сайта), а методом POST передаются только параметры, которые будут обработаны скриптом?

Comment: Или весь запрос сайта (получения hrml-разметки) вместе с данными в теле запроса считается методом POST в таком случае?

Comment: Назначение GET запроса получить некоторые данные от ресурса. Он не должен(по-идее) передавать никаких параметров в `uri`, кроме тех, что указывают на желаемый ресурс(Например `/cars/1` - тут мы в качестве параметра передали идентификатор конкретной машины. Или фильтр `/cars/?color=white`. Но тут мы по сути тоже лишь конкретизировали, что мы хотим получить). POST же напротив, ориентирован на передачу данных, которые прячет в своем теле. Он так-же может принимать `url` параметр, идентифицирующий ресурс. Например `PUT / cars/1` - обновить машину с id = 1 (PUT аналог POST)

Comment: По второму вопросу - мне кажется Вы путаете понятия запроса и ответа. Но отвечу как понял вопрос. Если на сайте есть POST форма, при переходе на этот сайт(в браузере) он будет запрошен методом GET. Вы не передадите никаких параметров, только укажете ресурс, который хотите получить(Например новость `/news/1`). Затем когда Вы на полученной разметке заполните поля формы и нажмете кнопку `submit`, будет выполнен еще запрос к серверу, и он уже будет POST, в теле которого будут лежать данные, которые Вы ввели в форму. Я правильно понял что Вы спрашивали?

Comment: Все понятно, всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 4):

1. Да.
2. Да, но не штатными средствами браузера. Только если с помощью инструментов разработчика или другим HTTP-клиентом, коих великое множество во главе с `curl`. И уж точно не стоит ожидать, что ответ будет таким же, т. к. разные "методы" предполагают совершение с запрашиваемым ресурсом разных действий (обычно GET это чтение, а POST это добавление нового).
3. Не совсем. *Формально* да, но поля, передаваемые в строке запроса, не могут в такой ситуации быть привязаны к полям формы, т. е. не могут быть изменены при пользовательском взаимодействии с веб-страницей (инструменты разработчика, конечно, могут всё). Что в `action`-атрибуте формы указано, то в строке запроса и уйдёт.
4. Из п. 3 следует, что это должна быть форма без полей. Даже у кнопки отправки формы должен отсутствовать атрибут `name`, иначе она тоже будет считаться полем формы и её значение будет отправлено в теле запроса.
5. Существуют, но не в типичных браузерах, разумеется. `telnet`, к примеру. Установите `telnet`-клиент и выполните в командной строке: `telnet mail.ru 80` (да, важно явно указать порт). Он подключится к серверу. Наберите приведённое вами тело как есть (у меня в PowerShell ввод почему-то не уходил эхом в стандартный вывод, но он воспринимался) и дважды переведите строку для завершения запроса. В стандартный вывод будет выведен ответ.
   Для HTTP**S** же потребуется что-нибудь посерьёзнее.

   Спускаться на **настолько** низкий уровень (`telnet` ничего не знает об HTTP) нужно только для очень узкого круга задач. Чтобы отправить сколько-нибудь нетривиальный запрос, надо погрузиться в дебри HTTP и преобразовать ваши данные в правильный для него формат. Поэтому для совершения произвольных HTTP-запросов чаще пользуются специализированными HTTP-клиентами. Например, вышеупомянутым `curl`. У многих скриптовых языков (Python, Ruby) также имеются HTTP-клиенты в стандартной библиотеке, оперирующие типами данных языка и занимающиеся преобразованием в нужные форматы самостоятельно.
6. Но зачем? Нет. Разметка страницы — результат не более чем одного запроса. Нет, фреймы открывают отдельные страницы, которые частью исходной не являются. Нет, загрузка с помощью JavaScript куска страницы не сделает этот кусок частью исходной; к тому же, JavaScript может быть выключен или не поддерживаться.

Я предполагаю, что вас интересует то, как голый браузер привык общаться по HTTP с помощью одного лишь HTML.

Но на HTML, формах и ссылках мир HTTP не ограничивается. Особенно сейчас, когда веб кишит разнообразными HTTP API и SPA на их основе. Современные браузеры не так просты: с помощью JavaScript они могут связывать практически любой ввод от пользователя с практически любым HTTP-запросом, нужно это лишь реализовать с помощью браузерного скрипта (кроме JavaScript на данный момент нет выбора).

Кроме того, нынче на просторах серверов, бывает, пасутся стада микросервисов, общающиеся (между собой и иногда даже между стадами) на языке HTTP словами на JSON/XML/и т. д. Там браузер не фигурирует ни на одной из сторон.

Answer (score 2):

1) Да, при входе на сайт отправляеться GET запрос, на что сервер выдает HTML страницу. Количество запросов может быть больше (если нужно еще запросить JS, картинки и т.п.).

2) Метод запроса можно задавать не только в теге форм. Запросы так же отправляются [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX).

Можно ли отправить POST запрос по той же ссылке? Это зависит от разработчиков, сделали ли он такую возможность. Так же нужно понимать что GET и POST запросы по одной ссылке могут вернуть совершенно разные ответы, так как POST запрос обрабатывается кодом, написаным разработчиками (или не обрабатывается, в таком случае 404 вернеться).

3,4) Да, можно использовать парамметры из ссылки при POST запросе и в обоих запросах парамметры передавать не обязательно.

5) Я пользуюсь [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/postman). Позволяет отправлять запросы с парамметрами или без.

6) Нет. Вы можете запросить ответ от сервера запросом, и если форма где-то внутри то нужно парсить полученный HTML.